# Is it possible to write recursive mysql queries to solve complex logic issue

Tags: php, mysql

I've one complex group module plan.

Tables Structure :

```
Group :
GroupID, GroupName, GroupImage, StatusID

GroupMembers :
GroupMemberID, GroupID, ModuleID, ModuleEntityID

Users :
UserID, FirstName, LastName

Modules :
ModuleTable, ModuleID
Group      -   1
User       -   2
Other      -   3
```

So in the group members table there are not just users, but even any old group itself can be a member of any group and if group is member of any group it means all that group members can automatically be a part of new group

example: lets say I've 2 members in group a and I created a group b with one member and group a, then group b will have have 3 members in total (of course it will be unique)

So in my table I'm inserting *moduleid* and *moduleentityid* (*userid / groupid*) in *GroupMembers* table.

**Complex part** :

If I create any group with the same persons then again if someone tries to create members with the same persons then it will not create a new record, but just return the existing one id. If it does not yet exists then a new record is created.

Issue with me is suppose I've 1 group x with members : a,b,c and d
and another group y with members : a and b

now I'm trying to create new group by adding c,d and group y so practically group y contains a and b so this group members will be a,b,c and d and I've already group x for it so it should return existing one instead of creating new.

But I've ModuleID and ModuleEntityID in table so I don't know how to compare it.

Please provide me at least any link or source

also think it like recursive group a may contains group b and group also contains group d and e and group e contains group x

So I need recursive mysql query to solve this problem

Thinking something like :

```
SELECT UserID FROM (
    @var:=SELECT IF(ModuleID=3,ModuleEntityID,@var) as UserID FROM GroupMembers
) tbl
```

TIA :)

Comment: MySQL does not support recursive queries. It even does not support window functions. MariaDB does support window functions, but still there is no support for recursive ones. If I were you, I would definitely switched to PostgreSQL. Otherwise you will have to write a whole lot of program code ...